# implementing method getMessages java

Tags: java

I have a question, I am implementing an application and I want my method getMessages of class user, return me
A list of all unread messages by the user.

When the user has read the message, it will mark it as read using the read method of the Message class.

The USER class is like this

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

public class User implements CompetitionListener {
private Platform platform;
private String username;
private String password;
private String fullName;
private List<Message> inbox;
private List<Message> outbox;
private List<Submission> submissions;

public User (Platform platform, String username, String password, String fullName) {
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.1: User constructor needed for user registration
    */
    this.platform = platform;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.inbox = new ArrayList<Message>();
    this.outbox = new ArrayList<Message>();
    this.submissions = new ArrayList<Submission>();
}

public User (User obj) {
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.3: Implementation of the copy constructor
    */
    this.platform = obj.platform;
    this.username = obj.username;
    this.password = obj.password;
    this.fullName = obj.fullName;
    this.inbox = obj.inbox;
    this.outbox = obj.outbox;
    this.submissions = obj.submissions;
}

public Boolean checkPassword(String password) {   
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.2: Implementation of checkPassword, required by login
    */
    return this.password.equals(password);        
}

public Organizer asOrganizer() {   
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.3: Create a new object for the Organizer Role
    */
    return new Organizer(this);
}

public Participant asParticipant() {
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.3: Create a new object for the Participant Role
    */
    return new Participant(this);
}

public String getUserName() {
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.1: Required by method findUser
    */
    return this.username;
}

public String getFullName() {
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.1: Required by test
    */
    return this.fullName;
}

public String toString() {        
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
sb.append(getFullName()).append("<").append(getUserName()).append(">");     
    return sb.toString();
   }

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.2: Required by test
    */
    if(obj==null) {
        return false;
    }        
    if (obj instanceof User) {
        User user = (User) obj;
        if (!this.username.equals(user.username) || !this.password.equals(user.password) || !this.fullName.equals(user.fullName)) {
            return false;
        }        
        // Additional checks can be added
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
   }

public List<Message> getMessages() {        
    return null;
   }

public Message sendMessage(String to, String subject, String message) throws CompetitionException
{ 

User receiver = platform.findUser(to);
if (to == null) {
    throw new CompetitionException(CompetitionException.RECIPIENT_NOT_FOUND);
}
else if(receiver == null ) {
    throw new CompetitionException(CompetitionException.RECIPIENT_NOT_FOUND); //Aquí debes lanza el tipo de excepción apropiado de tu lógica de negocio
}
Message m = new Message(this, this, subject, message);
return m;
}

public List<Competition> myCompetitions() {
    return null;
}
```

The MESSAGE class

```
  import java.text.DateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

 public class Message {

private String subject;
private String message;
private MessageStatus status;
private Date createdAt;
private User to;
private User from;

public Message (User from, User to, String subject, String message) {
    this.to = to;
    this.from = from;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message; 
    this.createdAt = new Date();
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}


public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

    public String getMessage () {
    return message;
}


public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void read() {

}

public MessageStatus getStatus() {    
    status = MessageStatus.PENDING;
    return this.status;
}
public void setStatus(MessageStatus r) {
    this.status = r;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public String toString() {                    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
    sb.append("{").append("date:").append("<").append(sdf.format(createdAt)).append(">,") 
        .append("from:").append("<").append(from).append(",").append("to:").append("<").append(to).append(",Subject:<").append(subject).append(">,status:<").append(getStatus()).append(">}");//append(price).append("}");

    return sb.toString();
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
   if(obj==null) {
        return false;
    }        
    if (obj instanceof Message) {
        Message message = (Message) obj;
        if (!this.from.equals(message.from) || !this.to.equals(message.to) || !this.status.equals(message.status)|| !this.message.equals(message.message)|| !this.subject.equals(message.subject)) 

        {
            return false;
        }        
        // Additional checks can be added
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}  


 }




public List<Message> getInbox() {        
    return this.inbox;
}

public List<Message> getOutbox() {        
    return this.outbox;
}    

public Platform getPlatform() {        
    return this.platform;
}

public void onNewEvaluation() {

}
public void onCompetitionClosed() {

}
```

}

I do not know how to implement the getMessages method of the USER class and the read of the Message class.

Comment: That's rather vague - what exactly are you struggling with? (by the way your `getStatus` method should probably not be setting the status of the message to pending)

Comment: This question is incomplete. How are you storing the Messages? In a database? How are users reading the messages? Is this a web app of some sort? A native app of some sort? Looking at it from way outside of the box...I would think you would need to set up an event handler for when the reading user clicks on the message to open it up. Then log it in some sort of storage (database, text file, etc.) that the message has been read, and update the state of the program...

Answer (score 0):

In your message class, you should have a flag that keep info if the message iis read or not.
On the basis of that check, you should traverse the list to find out unread/ read messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Message> getMessages() { 
        List<Message> temp = null;
        for(Message m:inbox)
        {
            if(m.getStatus.PENDING)
            {
                temp.add(m);
            }
        }
    return temp;
   }
```

There might be any syntax error because i haven't complied this but logically this works as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand what you are asking,
You want the method `getMessages` to return a list of all the messages that the user didn't read?

If this is the case, you can create a flag in the `Message` class, that will remember the status of the message.
Like this:

```
private boolean mReadFlag = false; //false - no, true - yes

...

//Will set the flag to read
public void read() {
    this.mReadFlag = true;
}

//Will return the read status
public boolean isRead(){
    return this.mReadFlag;
}
```

Then, in `User` class

```
public List<Message> getMessages() {     
    List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();

    for(Message message : YOUR_MESSAGE_LIST){
        if(!message.isRead()){
            messageList.add(message);
        }
    }

    return messageList;
}
```